# How to launch applications inside a logged in user from another logged in user?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, authentication

if users PC\A & PC\B are both logged in at the same time, with user A being locked , is there a way to launch an application on user A from within user B programmatically ,I don't mean run the application as user A what I mean is actually running the application in user A ?

any programming language or scripting language is fine with me but I'm including C++ tag fro windows API.

Comment: Theoretically you could create a Client-Server architecture, with User A running a server app that can spawn the application that User B's client requests

Comment: I do not wish any applications to be run in me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CreateProcessAsUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifying user A's token so the process runs in user A's account, and user A's desktop so the process runs in user A's login session.  This is how system services running in session 0 spawn processes in user sessions, for instance.